# Taking the derivative of both sides of a power series equation

Tags: derivatives, power-series

How to derivative both sides of

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\space\space\space x\in]-1,1[
$$

Answer is supposed to be

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3}\space\space\space x\in]-1,1[
$$

yet I get

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=-\frac{x+x^2}{(x-1)^3}\space\space\space x\in]-1,1[
$$

Is it due to $\vert{x}\vert<1$?

Comment: Isnt $(1-x) = -(x-1)$?

Comment: Why is that supposed to be the answer? Shouldn't it be $\sum n^2x^{n-1}$?

Comment: The derivative of the r.h.s. is $\;\dfrac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

What about beginning from something even more elementary?:

$$\text{For}\;\;|x|<1\,,\,\,\,\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\stackrel{\text{differ.}}\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{x^n}x\implies$$

$$\implies \frac x{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$

and once again differentiate:

$$\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^{n-1}$$

and if you multplicate both sides by $\;x\;$ then you get

$$\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n$$

and all the time the above is carried on within the convergence interval $\;x\in (-1,1)\iff |x|<1\;$